# NumberFormatException when using FileReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, parseint, numberformatexception

I have a plain text file with a few lines. Every line starts with an id:

```
1346  Salomon Shoes 129.99 7
```

All I need is to get the id into an 'int' variable. Why does it throw a NumberFormatException?

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\temp\\prices.txt"));

String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
String id = line.split(" ")[0];
int result = Integer.parseInt(id);
System.out.println(result + 1);
```

But it doesn't throw a NumberFormatException when I use consoleReader

```
BufferedReader consoleReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

and enter the exact same line!?

Comment: Besides the fact that you declare the variable as `bufferedReader` and then use it as `reader`, this code works just fine for me with the example file you've given. Perhaps something else is going on here?

Comment: UPD. That was my mistake with variable names. I especially have created clean class to test this code. Anyway - when I read a line from file, I got NumberFormatException. But when I read exact line from console - all works fine!...

Comment: @rbaloo Can you upload your input *prices.txt* file somewhere for us to take a look? Can you also update the question with exception stack trace?

Comment: And what dies the exception say?

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader;
String line = null;

try {
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
            "prices.txt"));
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String id[] = line.split(" ");

int result = Integer.parseInt(id[0]);
System.out.println(result + 1);
```